# how do I pass a user defined type variable to a function as a parameter?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to pass a user defined type parameter to a PLPGSQL function, but I am getting this error at runtime:

```
dev=# select process_shapes();
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "(,,7)"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function process_shapes() line 9 at SQL statement
dev=#
```

For some reason, the parameters are not passed correctly and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

My functions are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION join_shapes(first_shape shape_t,second_shape shape_t,OUT new_shape shape_t) 
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN   -- simplified join_shape()s function
    new_shape.num_lines:=first_shape.num_lines+second_shape.num_lines;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_shapes() 
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    rectangle       shape_t;
    triangle        shape_t;
    produced_shape  shape_t;
BEGIN
    rectangle.num_lines:=4;
    triangle.num_lines:=3;
    SELECT join_shapes(rectangle,triangle) INTO produced_shape;
    RAISE NOTICE 'produced shape = %s',produced_shape;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Type definition:

```
CREATE TYPE shape_t AS (
    shape_id            integer,
    shape_name          varchar,
    num_lines           integer
);
```

Postgres version: 9.6.1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, sorry, I am using 9.6.1 version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the target of a `SELECT ... INTO` statement is of a composite type, it will assign each of the columns returned by the `SELECT` to a different field in the target.

However, `SELECT join_shapes(rectangle,triangle)` returns a *single* column of type `shape_t`, and it's trying to cram the whole thing into the first column of the target, i.e. `produced_shape.shape_id` (hence the error message about a failed integer conversion).

Instead, you need a `SELECT` statement which returns three columns. Just replace

```
SELECT join_shapes(rectangle,triangle)
```

with

```
SELECT * FROM join_shapes(rectangle,triangle)
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
produced_shape := (SELECT join_shapes(rectangle,triangle));
```

which performs a single assignment, rather than trying to assign the target fields individually.

Comment: Wow, wouldn't figure that out ever. I though it was a problem with the input parameters and I was trying to convert shape_t to string with a ROW() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For other people whom want to pass composite types to functions:

```
create type pref_public.create_test_row_input as (
  name text
);

create or replace function pref_public.create_test_row(test_row pref_public.create_test_row_input) returns pref_public.test_rows as $$
    insert into pref_public.test_rows (name)
      values
        (test_row.name)
    returning *;
  $$ language sql strict security definer;
grant execute on function pref_public.create_test_row to pref_user;
```

You'll need to use `row()`

```
select * from pref_public.create_test_row(row('new row'));
```

More info [here](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/composite-types)